# Difference between shell variables which are exported and those which are not in bash

Tags: shell, environment-variables

Bash seems to differentiate between variables which have been exported and those which have not.

example:

```
$ FOO=BAR
$ env | grep FOO
$ set | grep FOO
FOO=BAR
```

`set` sees the variable but `env` does not.

```
$ export BAR=FOO
$ env | grep FOO
BAR=FOO
$ set | grep FOO
BAR=FOO
FOO=BAR
```

`set` sees both variables but `env` sees only the exported variable.

I know that `set` is a bash builtin and `env` is not.

What are the differences between variables which are exported and those which are not?

Comment: Terminology note: an “environment variable” is always exported. A non-exported variable is a “shell variable” (or “parameter”).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Exported variables are carried into the environment of commands executed by the shell that exported them, while non-exported variables are local to the current shell invocation. From the `export` man page:

> The shell shall give the export attribute to the variables corresponding to the specified names, which shall cause them to be in the environment of subsequently executed commands.

`set` outputs the current environment, which includes any local non-exported variables. `env` is used to launch programs in a new environment, and with no arguments will output what that new environment would be. Since `env` is creating a new environment, only exported variables are brought through, as is the case for any program launched from that shell. For example, spawning a second shell within the first (I used `$$` to represent prompts in the inner shell):

```
$ FOO=BAR
$ bash
$$ echo $FOO             # Note the empty line

$$ exit
$ export FOO
$ bash
$$ echo $FOO
BAR
$$
```

Note that it's the variable that's exported, not just its value. This means that once you `export FOO`, `FOO` becomes a global variable and shows up in subsequent environments, even if changed later:

```
$ export FOO
$ FOO=BAR
$ bash
$$ echo $FOO
BAR
$$
```

Comment: so if you're only concerned about the current shell, do you need to export? Separately, why would `locale` for the current shell not show the updates?