# How to print only defined variables (shell and/or environment variables) in bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables

The bash builtin command `set`, if invoked without arguments, will print all shell and environment variables, but also all defined functions. This makes the output unusable for humans and difficult to `grep`.

How can I make the bash builtin command `set` print only the variables and not the functions?

Are there other commands which prints only the shell variables, without the functions?

Note: bash differentiates between shell variables and environment variables. see here [Difference between environment variables and exported environment variables in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

"Are there other commands which prints only the shell variables, without the functions?"

In man bash, in section SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS (in the set section) it says:
"In posix mode,  only  shell variables  are listed."

```
(set -o posix; set)
```

note: `()` syntax spawns a subshell, if you don't like forking just use the more verbose version

```
set -o posix; set; set +o posix
```

Comment: By far the best solution

Comment: There are a bunch of usually uninteresting variables starting with `_`, which are easy to get rid of: `(set -o posix ; set | grep -v ^_)`

Comment: This has been bothering me too for so long!
Grepping away the lines that start with _ isn't enough if you have multi-line values, it will still leave the contents of the value in tact.  Since set prints the lines in order, all the _ lines will be at the end, so you can simply cut the results after the first _ line, using:
`set -o posix; set | sed -e '/^_/,$d'; set +o posix;`

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit enter before I was done and it only lets you edit comments for a 5 minute window...

Setting the -o posix setting will affect the rest of your bash shell session, so it's best to do it in a new invocation like so:

`bash -c "set -o posix; set | sed -e '/^_/,\$d';"`

Or if you want to alias it to a new command, for instance "printset", then put this in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile:

`alias printset="bash -c \"set -o posix; set | sed -e '/^_/,\\\$d';\""`

Then you can just run something like `printset | grep PATH` for instance

Comment: Just a note: the brackets are important in `(set -o posix; set)`. Without the brackets the behavior of the current Bash shell would be changed to match the Posix standard. (Dunno what that means but looks important.) With the brackets, the Bash remains unchanged.

Comment: Another way to trigger the POSIX behavior : `(POSIXLY_CORRECT= set)`

Comment: **Side effects**: Sets `POSIXLY_CORRECT=y` and adds `posix` to `$SHELLOPTS`

Answer (score 36):

Here are some workarounds:

```
$ comm -3 <(declare | sort) <(declare -f | sort)
```

breakdown:

1. `declare` prints every defined variable (exported or not) and function.
2. `declare -f` prints only functions.
3. `comm -3` will remove all lines common to both. In effect this will remove the functions, leaving only the variables.

To only print variables which are not exported:

```
$ comm -3 <(comm -3 <(declare | sort) <(declare -f | sort)) <(env | sort)
```

---

Another workaround:

```
$ declare -p
```

This will only print the variables, but with some ugly attributes.

```
declare -- BASH="/bin/bash"
declare -ir BASHPID=""
declare -A BASH_ALIASES='()'
declare -a BASH_ARGC='()'
...
```

You can cut the attributes away using... cut:

```
$ declare -p | cut -d " " -f 3
```

One downside is that the value of IFS is interpreted instead of displayed.

compare:

```
$ comm -3 <(declare | sort) <(declare -f | sort)
...
IFS=$' \t\n'
...
$ declare -p | cut -d " " -f 3
...
IFS="
"
...
```

This makes it quite hard to use that output for further processing, because of that lone `"` in one line. Perhaps some IFS-fu can be done to prevent this.

---

Yet another workaround, using `compgen`:

```
$ compgen -v
```

The bash builtin `compgen` was meant to be used in completion scripts. To this end, `compgen -v` lists all defined variables. The downside: it lists only the variable names, not the values.

Here is a hack to also list the values.

```
$ compgen -v | while read var; do printf "%s=%q\n" "$var" "${!var}"; done
```

The advantage: it is a pure bash solution. The disadvantage: some values are messed up because of the interpretation through `printf`. Also the subshell from the pipe and/or the loop add some extra variables.

Comment: does your `declare ...| cut` pipe break if there are no attributes for a variable?  I'm guessing that `--` is used in that case, but I'm still uneasy. `sed` might be safer, i.e. `declare -p | sed 's/^.* \([^ ]\+\)$/\1/'`

Comment: For `declare -p | cut -d " " -f 3`, you have to be careful, cuz some variables has multiline values.

Answer (score 14):

The `typeset` builtin strangely has an option to show functions only (`-f`) but not to show parameters only. Fortunately, `typeset` (or `set`) displays all parameters before all functions, function and parameter names cannot contain newlines or equal signs, and newlines in parameter values are quoted (they appear as `\n`). So you can stop at the first line that doesn't contain an equal sign:

```
set | awk -F '=' '! /^[0-9A-Z_a-z]+=/ {exit} {print $1}'
```

This only prints the parameter names; if you want the values, change `print $1` to `print $0`.

Note that this prints all parameter names (parameters and variables are used synonymously here), not just environment variables (“environment variable” is synonymous with “exported parameters”).

Note also that this assumes there is no environment variable with a name that doesn't match bash's constraints on parameter names. Such variables cannot be created inside bash but can have been inherited from the environment when bash starts:

```
env 'foo ()
{
  =oops' bash
```

Comment: Great solution!  I didn't even think of just stopping at the first line that doesn't have a '='. +1

Comment: Equivalently, with sed:  `set | sed '/=/!Q'`

Answer (score 8):

I am unsure how one can make `set` print only variables.  However by looking at the output of `set`, I was able to come up with the following that seems to grab just variables:

```
$ set | grep "^\([[:alnum:]]\|[[:punct:]]\)\+="
```

Basically, I am looking for lines that start with letters, numbers, or punctuation followed by a "=".  From the output that I saw, this grabs all of the variables; however, I doubt that this is very portable.

If, as your title suggests, you want to subtract from this list the variables that are exported and thus get a list of non-exported variables, then you could do something like this

```
$ set | grep "^\([[:alnum:]]\|[[:punct:]]\)\+=" | sort > ./setvars && env | sort | comm -23 ./setvars -
```

To break this down a bit, here is what it does:

1. `set | grep "^\([[:alnum:]]\|[[:punct:]]\)\+=" | sort > ./setvars` : This hopefully gets all of the variables (as discussed before), sorts them, and sticks the result in a file.
2. `&& env | sort`: After the previous command is complete, we are going to call `env` and sort its output.
3. `| comm -23 ./setvars -`: Finally, we pipe the sorted output of `env` into `comm` and use the `-23` option to print the lines that are unique to the first argument, in this case the lines unique to our output from set.

When you are done you might want to cleanup the temp file that it created with the command `rm ./setvars`

Comment: The problem with your command is not portability (it's specific to bash, of course, but there's no problem on the grep side). The problem is that you're grabbing some lines in function definitions. Bash indents most of the function code, but not all of it, in particular not text inside here documents (`f () {|cat <<EOF|foo=bar|EOF|}` where `|` represents a line break).

Answer (score 7):

Just use the command `env`.  It does not print functions.

Comment: It does if used inside a script.

Answer (score 3):

Try the command printenv:

```
$printenv
```

Comment: printenv and env only print exported (environment) variables and not non-exported (shell) variables.

Comment: @Lri Thanks!  I wondered how to print out just the exported variables.

Answer (score 3):

In bash, this will print only variable names:

```
compgen -v
```

Or, if values are needed also, use:

```
declare -p
```

Comment: thank you for your effort. please note that i have already mentioned that possibility in my answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5691/1170 have an upvote anyway.

Answer (score 1):

diffing against a clean shell to ensure also vars from rc scripts get left out

```
## get mostly local vars
diff_env(){
    diff <(bash -cl 'set -o posix && set') \
        <(set -o posix && set && set +o posix) | \
        grep -E "^>|^\+" | \
        grep -Ev "^(>|\+|\+\+) ?(BASH|COLUMNS|LINES|HIST|PPID|SHLVL|PS(1|2)|SHELL|FUNC)" | \
        sed -r 's/^> ?|^\+ ?//'
}
```

the version with `comm` would be too convoluted

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great. I'm offering an alternative that doesn't involve setting POSIX mode:

Here's the technique I've been using to store function state to a file so I can continue it later.  The first produces a state dump and the second produces just a list of the variable names.

```
set 2>/dev/null | while read a; do [[ $a == *=* ]] || break; echo $a; done 

set 2>/dev/null | while read a; do [[ $a == *=* ]] || break; echo ${a/=*}; done
```

Both work by dumping lines until it finds one without an '=' char, which occurs when the first function is listed. The latter crops the assignment off.