# How to print apparently hidden environment variables?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, environment-variables

Environment variables can be shown with `env`; but, some are not shown. For example...

`echo $EUID` might produce as result of `1000` yet
`env | grep EUID` produces no result.

What is this type of variable? A read-only environment variable?

Do all shells set the same variables by some convention?

How does one go about listing these hidden variables?

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-print-all-environment-variables-defined-but-not-necessarily-exported-in

Comment: Not all shell variables are environment variables, only those that are marked for export by, e.g., the `export` command.

Comment: Related (on [ubuntu.se]): [Why aren't variables like $PS1 in printenv?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960551/why-arent-variables-like-ps1-in-printenv)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `set` command shows all variables (and functions), not just the exported ones, so

```
set | grep EUID
```

will show you the desired value. This command should show all the non-exported variables:

```
comm -23 <(set | grep '^[^=[:space:]]\+=' | sort) <(env | sort)
```

Comment: Unfortunately 'set' can add quotes while 'env' does not as such this will list some variables (often very long ones), which are actually exported environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are no *hidden* environment variables.
All are printed with either `env` or `printenv`.

What you did was print the value of a variable `EUID`, but that variable is not exported.

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
$ bash -c 'declare -p EUID'
declare -ir EUID="1000"
```

That is: (`i`) for integer and (`r`) for readonly. No (`x`) for exported, though.

[zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)

```
$ zsh -c 'typeset -p EUID'
typeset -i10 EUID=1000
```

That is (`i`) for integer, (`10`) for base 10 (decimal).

Instead:

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
$ bash -c 'declare -p PATH'
declare -x PATH="…"
```

[zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)

```
$ zsh -c 'typeset -p PATH'
export PATH=…
```