# What do the bash-builtins 'set' and 'export' do?

Tags: bash, shell

I am at a bit of a loss as to the purpose of `set` and `export` in Bash (and I guess probably other shells too).

I would think it is for setting environment variables, but that can be done just with `VARIABLE=VALUE`, right?

Also typing `set` and `export` on their own show different values.

So what is their purpose?

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b

Comment: I always start by bash script with the following two. #!/usr/bin/env bash set -euxo pipefail This link beautifully explains the same. **https://coderwall.com/p/fkfaqq/safer-bash-scripts-with-set-euxo-pipefail**

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`export` marks the given variable as exported to children of the current process, by default they are not exported. For example:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo "$foo"
bar
$ bash -c 'echo "$foo"'

$ export foo
$ bash -c 'echo "$foo"'
bar
```

`set`, on the other hand, sets shell attributes and the positional parameters.

```
$ set foo=baz
$ echo "$1"
foo=baz
```

Note that `baz` is not assigned to `foo`, it simply becomes a literal positional parameter. There are many other things `set` can do (mostly shell options), see `help set`.

As for printing, `export` called with no arguments prints all of the variables in the shell's environment. `set` also prints variables that are *not* exported. It can also export some other objects (although you should note that this is not portable), see `help export`.

Comment: Thanks that is a very useful answer. However, when I set http_proxy just with http_proxy=http://abc.com, it is visible to child processes, e.g. running wget without me exporting it. How can this be?

Comment: @mydoghasworms Two possible reasons. One, you are running the command as `foo=bar command`. This is an implicit export for a single command. The second possibility is that `http_proxy` is already exported in your environment before you modify it.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

See `help set` or `info bash set`: set is used to set shell attributes and positional parameters.

Variables that are not exported are not inherited by child processes. `export` is used to mark a variable for export.

Answer (score -1):

you can think of the 'export' command as turning the variable global...

for better understanding I would append to the previous answers the following example:

```
x=1
bash -c 'echo $x'
# nothing show

export x
bash -c 'echo $x'
# value of x shown
```

- for windows users the use of 'set' is confusing
  because the command is 'accepted' (gives no error)

Comment: this appears to be almost identically the same answer as that posted by Chris Down more than 9 years ago

Comment: is you look closely you will get the nuance of using export in a existing variable... of course this will be more valuable after several commands... or in a script where you want to decide if a previous local variable will be promoted to global...  ;-)

Comment: isn't that exactly what the `export foo` does in that earlier answer? You're even using the same example command to see if the launched command sees the envvar or not...

Comment: ...and I mentioned previous answers in my answer... but if do not understand the 'nuance' I can't really do much more... I think the noted possibility of decision of 'optional' export of a local variable decided elsewhere in a long script should be enough to be valuable for any programmer... ;-)