# Variables setted in shell are not read with in "bash -c 'command'"

Tags: shell

Input:

```
sudo bash -c '>> /media/$USER/rootfs/etc/profile'
```

Output:

```
bash: /media/root/rootfs/etc/profile: No such file or directory
```

Input:

```
TEST=$USER
sudo bash -c '>> /media/$TEST/rootfs/etc/profile'
```

Output:

```
bash: /media//rootfs/etc/profile: No such file or directory
```

Instead of:

```
/media/riccardo/rootfs/etc/profile
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell variables aren't exported to commands launched from the shell, by default.

You need to explicitly do it with `export`, e.g.:

```
$ export test=foo
$ bash -c 'echo test=$test'
test=foo
```

Except that `sudo` may still clean up the environment before passing it to `bash`, so you may need to use the command line arguments instead:

```
$ test=foobar 
$ sudo bash -c 'echo "$1"' sudo_bash "$test"
foobar
```

No need to `export` here, and `sudo_bash` is just a string that's used as the "name" of that inner shell, you'd see it if the `-c` string had e.g. a syntax error.

See also:

- [how to pass environment variable to sudo su](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202383/170373)
- [What do the bash-builtins 'set' and 'export' do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71144/what-do-the-bash-builtins-set-and-export-do)

Comment: Thank you ilkkachu, also if i have found an more elegant solution:

Comment: sudo bash -c ">> /media/$USER/rootfs/etc/profile"

Comment: double quotes instead of single quotes solve my problem.

Comment: @RiccardoLaMarca, ah, I should have mentioned that in the first place. In general, **_don't_** use double quotes like that. If you do, the contents of the variable get expanded as part of the inner shell's command line, _just like any other code there_. Shell metacharacters and expansions get processed, so they can break the structure of the command and even cause security issues. Try e.g. `test='foo;bar'; bash -c "echo $test"`

Comment: Wow, it's true, this issue was not known to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting problems

```
sudo bash -c '>> /media/'"$USER"'/rootfs/etc/profile'
test=$USER
sudo bash -c '>> /media/'"$test"'/rootfs/etc/profile'
```

`''` quotes are literal, `""` quotes allow expansion of variables. I have use both, concatenating them together. It would also work if I only used `""`.

Comment: This has exactly the issue with unsafe expansion of `$USER` or `$test` in the command line interpreted by the shell started from `sudo`.

Comment: What is the danger? These variables are expanded by the calling shell, so you have to be responsible for ensuring they are correct, and won't cause a problem. Can you explain what the danger is?

Comment: The usual, shell metacharacters and whitespace being interpreted as part of the command, and not just as pure data. Compare `test='foo;bar'; sudo bash -c 'echo /media/'"$test"'/rootfs/etc/profile'` and `test='foo;bar'; sudo bash -c 'echo /media/"$1"/rootfs/etc/profile' sh "$test"`. Sure, `$USER` _probably_ contains just letters and digits, but it's not hard to use command line args or the environment to pass the value safely.

Comment: @ilkkachu oh yes. Would I need to add more quotes (for sudo). You can edit if you like.