# Bash aliases not loaded on Debian, but on Mint they do when sudo -s

Tags: bash, debian, ssh, alias

The very same `ls` aliases are defined on both machines:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_aliases | grep -e "alias ls=" -e "alias l=" -e "alias lll="
alias ls='\ls --kibibytes --color=always --group-directories-first'
alias l='ls'
alias lll='l -la'
```

### Linux Mint (18.1)

(I sit at this machine.)

```
$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for ...

$ lll
(very long list of files)
```

---

### GNU/Linux Debian Stretch (9, testing)

(I `ssh` to this machine.)

```
$ ssh username@ip_address_of_server -p port_number

$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for ...

$ lll
lll: command not found
```

---

### Question

How do I achieve the goal to have my personal aliases sourced when `sudo -s` on Debian like it works on Linux Mint?

---

### `sudo -s` explanation

`sudo -s` sources aliases on my Linux Mint, whereas `sudo -i` or `su` or `su -` do not.

It is working for my purposes on Linux Mint, I have a lot of useful aliases defined and I want it also to work on my Debian server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to source the `.bash_alias` file in the right shell initialisation file. The initialisation file varies on how the shell is started. And calling it on via ssh and on a local machine are different. But then calling it again with `sudo -s` makes it the same on both machines, because it starts an interactive non-login root shell. But to get the same aliases, you need the have the same definitions.

If you stick to `sudo -s`, it's enough to source your `.bash_aliases` file in the ssh user's `.bashrc`. So it's enough to add this line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
. ~/.bash_aliases
```

Notice that the `lll` alias works on your Mint before you `sudo -s` and it won't do so on Debian, because that's an ssh session, so a login shell, while on Mint it's just interactive. If you want the aliases to be available right away on the ssh Debian, you'll have to add another sourcing to your `.profile` file.

This is quite convoluted and to get the whole picture, you need to do some reading and learn about login and interactive shells. `man bash` has it all. You can take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303092/181255) to have an idea of what this is about. Don't skip the comments below that answer!