# Why does LC_MESSSAGES need to be exported on macOS homebrew bash to take effect?

Tags: bash, osx, locale, homebrew

On macOS, with bash installed from homebrew, I noticed that setting `LC_MESSAGES` seems to have some effect on the current shell's locale settings, but messages doesn't actually change until `LC_MESSAGES` is exported:

Unsetting `LANG` and `LC_MESSAGES`, I get an English error message as expected:

```
bash-4.4$ unset LANG LC_MESSAGES
bash-4.4$ if :;  fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

Setting `LC_MESSAGES` to an incorrect value gives an error about `setlocale`:

```
bash-4.4$ LC_MESSAGES=foo
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_MESSAGES: cannot change locale (foo): No such file or directory
```

So *something* changes when I set `LC_MESSAGES`. But setting it to a reasonable value has no effect:

```
bash-4.4$ LC_MESSAGES=ja_JP.UTF-8
bash-4.4$ if :;  fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

Until I export it:

```
bash-4.4$ export LC_MESSAGES
bash-4.4$ if :;  fi
bash: 予期しないトークン `fi' 周辺に構文エラーがあります
```

(All of this goes for `LANG` as well, it seems.)

The Bash manual's section on [Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) does not say `LC_MESSAGES` or `LANG` has to be exported (and most other variables listed there don't have to be exported).

Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between environment variables and exported environment variables in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b)

Comment: @Scott thanks, but what am I supposed to see there? As I said, the documentation does not say the variable has to be exported, and setting an unexported `LC_MESSAGES` does have some effect. How does that post explain either of these observations?

Comment: When you set a plain, ordinary, local shell variable, the shell just puts it into memory. The `LANG` and `LC_*` variables are a special case; they get validated when assigned in a way that no (few?) other variables do. But the point is that variables don’t become visible (especially to external programs) and effective until they are exported, and transformed from shell variables into environment variables. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … The fact that you need to do this to get bash *itself* to honor them is a little odd, but the explanation is probably that they are using library code (suitable for running in *any* program), and that library code calls other library functions like `getenv`, and there’s no mechanism for short-circuiting them to look for a ***shell variable*** called `LC_MESSAGES` when no environment variable by that name exists.

Comment: While I can't reproduce with 4.4 on GNU/Linux (changes taken into account when exported or not), I can on FreeBSD.

Comment: @Scott, that library should use `setlocale()`, not `getenv()` to query the current locale. `bash` as shown by the OP does call `setlocale()` when the `LC_*` variables are modified to set the current locale, so it seems there's something wrong with that library or possibly the way `bash` uses it.

Comment: @Scott But this isn't simple validation, though. `setlocale` *is* being called, and AFAIK that function doesn't have an option to just validate but not set.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Bash's internal gettext library switches to calling `getenv()` if `setlocale()` is not available. It _is_ available on macOS though... but maybe the Homebrew build scripts are't picking it up, or are ignoring it for whatever reason.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I can reproduce on FreeBSD with a simple program that calls `setlocale("fr_FR.UTF-8", LC_ALL)` followed by `dgettext()`. The messages are not translated into the language passed to `setlocale()` (though `truss` shows the corresponding `.mo` file is being open if there's no `LC_*` variable in the environment), but instead  into the language referenced by the LC_* variables. One would need to look at the source to see why, but that very much looks like a bug.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas do you also see in the other *BSDs? OpenBSD, NetBSD?

Comment: I've only tested in FreeBSD (most of macOS is based on FreeBSD, though I can't tell if that applies to that particular case).

Comment: @JohnDoea Similar behaviour on OpenBSD.

Comment: @Scott can you remove your duplicate flag now? As the answer shows, this goes well beyond simple `export`ing of variables.

Comment: Funny, I'm still getting `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'` even after exporting and no Japanese text. `locale` however reflects the change. Anyone knows anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that assigning the `LC_*` shell variables does cause `bash` to call POSIX `setlocale()` for the corresponding category with the value of the variable whether they're exported or not. For `LANG`, it calls `setlocale(LC_ALL, thevalue)` followed `setlocale(LC_*)` again for all the `LC_*` variable. For `LANGUAGE`, it doesn't do anything.

Now, `bash` is the shell of the GNU project. For localization of text, it uses GNU `gettext`, also known as `libintl`. It even comes with its own version bundled with the source which you can compile in `bash` if you call the `configure` script with `--with-included-gettext`.

`gettext` looks up message translations in a per-language database. Which language it is is determined by the value of `LC_MESSAGES` category though can be overridden by the `$LANGUAGE` environment variable.

According to the gettext documentation, the previous call to `setlocale()` should be the one that determines the value for the category, but there are some complications:

For multithreaded applications, [there is currently no standard API that gettext can use to retrieve that value](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=861). `bash` is not a multithreaded application, but even what [`setlocale(category, NULL)` returns is *implementation defined* and in practice not always usable](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gettext.git/tree/gettext-runtime/intl/localename.c?h=v0.19.8.1#n2789).

So in practice, gettext only uses `setlocale()` to retrieve the language name when built as part of the GNU libc or on a system where the libc is the GNU libc (like the one built with `bash` with `--with-included-gettext` on a GNU system) because it knows it can rely on it.

On other systems, it uses `getenv()` to determine the locale, irrespective of how `setlocale()` was invoked earlier, which is why you're seeing that behaviour.

Exporting those variables is an easy work around. One could argue that if they're not exported, they're not part of the environment anyway. POSIX is not very clear on that. Another way to look at it is that the translation is not done by `bash`, but by a third party mechanism, so just like when *executing* other commands, we need to use environment variables to pass  the locale information between the two software (here `bash` and `gettext`).

Now, on GNU systems, it actually gets worse.

As seen above, gettext is included in the GNU libc. `$LANGUAGE` takes precedence over `$LC_MESSAGE` but `$LANGUAGE` is not part of the POSIX locale API, that's an extension on top of it.

So while on a GNU system, gettext will use `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, NULL)` to get the name for the LC_MESSAGES category, for `LANGUAGE`, it always uses `getenv()`, `LANGUAGE` is not a locale category.

The problem is that `bash` manages the environment by itself as part of its variable handling, disconnected from the libc's `environ[]` array. It does have its own `getenv()` which does query its own version of the environment, but when `gettext` is built as part of the libc, and `bash` is dynamically linked `dgettext()` calls the `getenv()` from the libc as that's an internal call within the libc, not `bash`'s one, so will only get the `$LANGUAGE` value from the time `bash` was started.

So on GNU systems, unless `bash` was linked statically or built with `--with-included-gettext`, any change to `$LANGUAGE` will be ignored for the messages generated by `bash`, whether the variable is exported or not. On other systems, that's fine (as long as `$LANGUAGE` is exported) as gettext is not part of the libc, so it does call `bash`'s `getenv()`.

On Debian:

```
$ LANGUAGE=fr bash -c 'LANGUAGE=es; eval fi'
bash: eval: ligne 0: erreur de syntaxe près du symbole inattendu « fi »
bash: eval: ligne 0: `fi'
```

(message in French, the value of `$LANGUAGE` at the time `bash` was invoked, not Spanish).

Actually it's not much better with other shells.

`zsh` is not translated to other languages but does use `strerror()` which does use `gettext` internally on GNU systems:

```
$ LANGUAGE=fr zsh -c 'LANGUAGE=es; true</x; LANGUAGE=en; true</a; true < /etc/shadow'
zsh:1: no existe el archivo o el directorio: /x
zsh:1: no existe el archivo o el directorio: /a
zsh:1: permission denied: /etc/shadow
```

The `LANGUAGE=es` was honoured but see how the second message for ENOENT has not been displayed in English (presumably cached by gettext somehow; that cache should have been invalidated when `$LANGUAGE` changed but that was not the case).

Comment: Wow, that's a tricky puzzle you unraveled!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/26322) for an explaination of the difference between a shell variable and an environment variable.  In essence:

Setting a shell variable:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Setting an environment variable:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

You want to set environment variables for locale, as shell variables are private to the shell and won’t be passed to child processes.

Comment: That's different here. `export` is only needed to affect the behaviour of commands being executed. Here, we're talking of messages generated by the shell internally.

Comment: There are no child processes here, though. That's why I specifically used this `if :; fi` command, which generates a syntax error from the shell itself.

Comment: It is the assignment that creates the problem.  Assignment of a variable is a command that gets forked off.  The setlocale child process doesn’t see the shell variable assignment and told bash that it didn’t work.  Bash reported the assignment didn’t work, and told you what your attempted assignment was.

Comment: That ... makes no sense. Simple variable  assignment doesn't fork off a new process in any shell that I know of. And as for `setlocale` telling Bash that it didn't work, there are *two* assignments here, and `setlocale` only complained about one of them. Going by your logic, it should have complained about both.

Comment: That's not "simple" variable assignment, though, is it? You're running that in the background.

Comment: My point was supposed to be that processes run when you assign a LC_ variable to either the shell or environment.