# When defining an environment variable, I get "Command not found"

Tags: environment-variables, tcsh

When I type `HELLO="hello"`, I would expect to create an environment variable called HELLO. Instead, I get the error `HELLO=hello: Command not found.` What could be going wrong here?

I am on Debian GNU/Linux 9.12, on a shared server where I am not root.

Comment: Why do you expect it to create an **environment** variable? It should create a shell variable, you have to use `export` to copy it into the environment. Do you know the difference?

Comment: I meant to create a shell variable. Now I know the difference.

Comment: Anyone else with a similar problem, make sure not to include a $ dollar sign at the start. Do NOT type `$HELLO="hello"`, this is where I went wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the right command to set a shell variable. Or would be, in a POSIX shell. It doesn't actually export the variable to the environment of commands you run, though. To do that, you'd need `export HELLO` in addition.

See e.g. [Difference between shell variables which are exported and those which are not in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3507/170373) for the difference.

Anyway, the error message you get appears to match the one `tcsh` gives:

```
$ tcsh
~> HELLO="hello"
HELLO=hello: Command not found.
```

And it has a different language. Either use `setenv HELLO "hello"` to set a variable exported to commands, or `set HELLO = "hello"` for one that doesn't get exported. Or try to see if you can change your shell to something else (e.g. Bash or Zsh) if you want a POSIX-like shell instead.

Comment: most popular would be bash: try running `$ bash` (type `bash` as your normal user) to start a bash shell

Comment: Since he didn't use `export`, the actual equivalent would be `set HELLO = "hello"`

Comment: @Barmar, mm, or since they said they wanted an environment variable, I should have said that `HELLO="hello"` is fine, except it doesn't actually export it.

Comment: I suspect they just don't know the difference between environment and shell variables, and mistakenly use the first term. I've seen it many times. I've also seen many people use `export` unnecessarily.